Synchronizing Movements with Socket.IO
This is the first time that I'm using socket.io and I'm having troubles understanding how to coordinate the "character" I'm showing. Basically each of my user have a ship that they should be able to move right and left (right now only turn the image facing left and right) and also see the opponent ship. What I'd like to accomplish is that when Username1 move their ship they see the you-ship-img ship facing the direction of their choice while Username2 should also see the movement Username1 does in the other-ship-img. So when Username1 move they see their own ship move and Username2 see the movement of the Username1 in the other-img move. Of course the same should happens viceversa for when Username2 move
this is my code right now:
index.js
const express=require("express")
const app=express()

const path=require("path")
const http=require("http")
const {Server}=require("socket.io")


const server=http.createServer(app)

const io=new Server(server)
app.use(express.static(path.resolve("")))

let users=[]
let playingArray=[]

io.on("connection",(socket)=>{

    socket.on("find",(e)=>{

        if(e.subjectCode!=null){

            users.push(e.subjectCode)

            if(users.length>=2){
                let subject1Obj={
                    subject1Code:users[0],
                    // subject1Mouse:,
                    p1value:"X",
                    subject1Move:""
                }
                let subject2Obj={
                    subject2Code:users[1],
                    p2value:"O",
                    subject2Move:""
                }

                let obj={
                    subject1:subject1Obj,
                    subject2:subject2Obj,
                    sum:1
                }
                playingArray.push(obj)

                users.splice(0,2)

                io.emit("find",{allPlayers:playingArray})

            }

        }

    })

    socket.on("playing",(e)=>{
        if(e.value=="X"){
            let objToChange=playingArray.find(obj=>obj.subject1.subject1Code===e.subjectCode)

            objToChange.subject1.subject1Move=e.id
            objToChange.sum++
        }
        else if(e.value=="O"){
            let objToChange=playingArray.find(obj=>obj.subject2.subject2Code===e.subjectCode)
            objToChange.subject2.subject2Move=e.id
            objToChange.sum++
        }

        io.emit("playing",{allPlayers:playingArray})

    })

    socket.on("gameOver",(e)=>{
        playingArray=playingArray.filter(obj=>obj.subject1.subject1Code!==e.subjectCode)
        // console.log(playingArray)
    })
})


app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    return res.sendFile("index.html")
})

server.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log("port connected to 5000")
})

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Tilt+Warp&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
        font-family: 'Tilt Warp', cursive;
    }

    h1 {
        margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
        font-size: 5rem;
        color: rgb(32, 183, 93);
        -webkit-text-stroke: .5px black;
    }

    input {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }

    button {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    img {
        width: 30px;
    }

    #cont {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .btn {

        font-size: 2rem;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: rgb(206, 203, 203);
        border-radius: 10px;

    }

    #find {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 7px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        width: 250px;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }

    .btn:hover {
        background-color: rgb(226, 228, 230);
    }

    button.enabled {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <h1>SpaceWar</h1>


    <div style="display: flex; width: 95vw; position: relative;">
        <p id="userCont">You: <span id="user"></span></p>
        <p style="position: absolute; right: 0;" id="oppNameCont">Opponent: <span id="oppName"></span></p>

    </div>
    <br>
    <p id="valueCont">You are playing as <span id="value"></span></p>
    <br>
    <p id="whosTurn">X's Turn</p>
    <div>
        <p style="font-size: 1.2rem;" id="enterCode">Username: </p>

        <input type="text" placeholder="Codice" id="subjectCode" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <button id="find">Search player</button>
    <img id="loading" src="loading.gif" alt="">

    <div id="bigcont">
      <div class="other">
        <div class="other-ship"><img id="othershipImg" class="other-ship-img" src="" alt=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="you">
        <div class="you-ship"><img id="youshipImg" class="you-ship-img" src="" alt=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="leftBtn" class="btn button-left">Left</button>
        <button id="rightBtn" class="btn button-right">Right</button>
      </div>
    </div>


</body>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>


<script>
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById("bigcont").style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById("userCont").style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById("oppNameCont").style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById("valueCont").style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById("whosTurn").style.display = "none"

    const socket = io();

    let subjectCode;

    document.getElementById('find').addEventListener("click", function () {
      subjectCode = document.getElementById("subjectCode").value
        document.getElementById("user").innerText = subjectCode
        if (subjectCode == null || subjectCode == '') {
            alert("Insert username.")
        }
        else {

            socket.emit("find", { subjectCode: subjectCode })

            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block"
            document.getElementById("find").disabled = true;

        }
    })



    socket.on("find", (e) => {


        let allPlayersArray = e.allPlayers
        console.log("html",allPlayersArray)

        if (subjectCode != '') {
            document.getElementById("userCont").style.display = "block"
            document.getElementById("oppNameCont").style.display = "block"
            document.getElementById("valueCont").style.display = "block"
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none"
            document.getElementById("subjectCode").style.display = "none"
            document.getElementById("find").style.display = "none"
            document.getElementById("enterCode").style.display = "none"
            document.getElementById("bigcont").style.display = "block"
            document.getElementById("whosTurn").style.display = "block"
            document.getElementById("whosTurn").innerText = "X's Turn"


        }

        let oppName
        let value

        const foundObject = allPlayersArray.find(obj => obj.subject1.subject1Code == `${subjectCode}` || obj.subject2.subject2Code == `${subjectCode}`);
        foundObject.subject1.subject1Code == `${subjectCode}` ? oppName = foundObject.subject2.subject2Code : oppName = foundObject.subject1.subject1Code
        foundObject.subject1.subject1Code == `${subjectCode}` ? value = foundObject.subject1.p1value : value = foundObject.subject2.p2value

        document.getElementById("oppName").innerText = oppName
        document.getElementById("value").innerText = value

        document.querySelector(".you-ship").classList.add(`${subjectCode}`);

        // <div class="you-ship"><img id="meshipImg" class="me-ship-image" src="" alt=""></div>

        document.querySelector(".other-ship").classList.add(`${oppName}`);

        document.querySelector(".you-ship-img").classList.add(`${subjectCode}`);
        document.querySelector(".other-ship-img").classList.add(`${oppName}`);

        document.getElementById("othershipImg").src = "shipB.png";
        document.getElementById("youshipImg").src = "shipA.png";


    })


document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(e => {
        e.addEventListener("click", function () {
            let value = document.getElementById("value").innerText

            socket.emit("playing", { value: value, id: e.id, subjectCode: subjectCode })

            // if (e.id === "leftBtn") {
            // document.getElementById("meshipImg").style.transform = "scaleX(-1)";
            // } else if (e.id === "rightBtn") {
            //     document.getElementById("meshipImg").style.transform = "scaleX(1)";
            // }
        })
    })

    socket.on("playing", (e) => {
    const foundObject = e.allPlayers.find(obj => obj.subject1.subject1Code == subjectCode || obj.subject2.subject2Code == subjectCode);
    const subject1Code = foundObject.subject1.subject1Code;
    const subject2Code = foundObject.subject2.subject2Code;

    console.log(foundObject)

    const p1id = foundObject.subject1.subject1Move;
    const p2id = foundObject.subject2.subject2Move;


    if (p1id !== '') {
      console.log(p1id)


        if (p1id == "rightBtn") {
          document.querySelectorAll(`.you-ship-img.${subject1Code}`).forEach(element => {
            element.style.transform = "scaleX(-1)";
        });
          document.querySelectorAll(`.other-ship-img.${subject2Code}`).forEach(element => {
            element.style.transform = "scaleX(-1)";
        });

        } else {
          document.querySelectorAll(`.you-ship-img.${subject1Code}`).forEach(element => {
            element.style.transform = "scaleX(1)";
        });
                document.querySelectorAll(`.other-ship-img.${subject2Code}`).forEach(element => {
            element.style.transform = "scaleX(1)";
        });
        }
    }
    if (p2id !== '') {
        if (p2id == "rightBtn") {
          document.querySelectorAll(`.you-ship-img.${subject2Code}`).forEach(element => {
            element.style.transform = "scaleX(-1)";
        });
        document.querySelectorAll(`.other-ship-img.${subject1Code}`).forEach(element => {
            element.style.transform = "scaleX(-1)";
        });
        } else {
          document.querySelectorAll(`.you-ship-img.${subject2Code}`).forEach(element => {
            element.style.transform = "scaleX(1)";
        });
                document.querySelectorAll(`.other-ship-img.${subject1Code}`).forEach(element => {
            element.style.transform = "scaleX(1)";
        });
        }
    }


    if ((foundObject.sum) % 2 == 0) {
        document.getElementById("whosTurn").innerText = "O's Turn";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("whosTurn").innerText = "X's Turn";
    }

});



</script>

</html>

Im not getting any error but only the you-ship-image change direction when the button left or right are clicked. the other-ship-image always facethe same direction

Checkout this article on medium: Simple Multiplayer Game with Socket.io Tutorial
